# Material UI Menu Button not populating options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using Material UI and React to get a 'Show More' Button to possibly work but it is not working. When I click the button, I am expecting a list of items to populate from `options` but nothing populates. I copied the code from the following sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zcxlye?file=/demo.js

But whenever I implement the code, it simply does not work, any suggestions?

**Initialized variables**:

```
const state = useSelector(state => state)
  const stateOfPosts = useSelector(state => state.posts)
  const stateOfComments = useSelector(state => state.comments.storage)
  const comments = sortBy(stateOfComments, 'date').reverse()
  const posts = [...new Set(sortBy(stateOfPosts, 'date').reverse())]
  const [savedUser, setSavedUser] = useState()
  const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState()
  const [replies, setReplies] = useState(false)
  const [numberOfPosts, setNumberOfPosts] = useState(Array.from({ length: 5}))
  const [hasMorePosts, setHasMorePosts] = useState(true)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)
  const menuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const [imageToView, setImageToView] = useState('')
  const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48
  const options = [
    'None',
    'Atria',
    'Callisto',
    'Dione',
    'Ganymede',
    'Hangouts Call',
    'Luna',
    'Oberon',
    'Phobos',
    'Pyxis',
    'Sedna',
    'Titania',
    'Triton',
    'Umbriel',
  ];
  const commentRef = useRef()
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
```

`handleMenuClick`:

```
const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      };
```

`handleMenuClose`:

```
const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
      };
```

**part of returned statement that deals with Menu Item logic**:

```
      <Grid item xs={12} container style={{backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: '20px'}}>
        {/* avatar, username, etc */}
        <Grid item xs={1} container style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <Avatar src={AvatarPicture} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container xs={11} style={{ gap: "10px" }}>
        <Grid item container xs={11}>
          <IconButton 
          aria-label="more"
          id='horz-button'
          aria-controls={menuOpen ? 'long-menu' : undefined}
          aria-expanded={menuOpen ? 'true' : undefined}
          aria-haspopup='true'
          onClick={handleMenuClick}
          style={{position: 'absolute', left: '95%', top: '0%'}}>
            <MoreHorizIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Menu
          id='long-menu'
          MenuListProps={{
            'aria-labelledby': 'horz-button'
          }}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={open}
          onClose={handleMenuClose}
          PaperProps={{
            style: {
              maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
              width: '20ch',
            },
          }}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option} selected={option === 'Pyxis'} onClick={handleMenuClose}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Menu>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={11}>
            @{posts[i]?.username}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={11}>
            {posts[i]?.location} {posts[i]?.date}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: Do you see any console errors? Either when page loads or after you click the show more button?

Comment: No i did not, everything seems to be working fine. I am wondering if it has to do with how my ```Grids``` are laid out?

Comment: I think you need to change `open={open}` to `open={menuOpen}` since `open` is initialized to false and `setOpen()` is never called so it just stays false.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It is always those little mistakes that cause huge issues...

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it did the trick. It is indeed always the little things.